# How many solvable configurations of the Rubik's cube have no two squares of the same color touching?

Tags: group-theory, recreational-mathematics, rubiks-cube

The [Superflip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superflip) (image below) is an example of a configuration where no two squares of the same color are adjacent.

[image: Rubiks Cube Superflip]

I'm interested to know how many solvable configurations (that is, those that you can reach from a solved cube) with no two squares of the same color adjacent exist (I found it hard to get there by randomly rotating sides).

- A related [question on Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/429/is-it-possible-to-scramble-a-rubiks-cube-such-that-no-two-squares-of-the-same-c?newreg=2cae1496c51747b688300bb23c228d54) provides examples of such configurations
- A [Quora question](https://www.quora.com/How-many-combinations-of-a-3X3X3-Rubiks-Cube-are-possible-where-not-any-two-adjacent-colours-are-the-same-anywhere-in-the-cube) and [Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2794292/permutations-of-rubiks-cube-such-that-no-adjacent-sticker-is-the-same) remain unanswered

Comment: If this question [already exists on the site](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2794292/167197), why would you ask it again? I think it would be more appropriate to [start a bounty](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on the original question to draw more attention to it.

Comment: That's fair, @MikePierce --- I saw the duplicate question after (and added a link to my question); should I have simply deleted my question? (My original search on Google for `rubiks cube no two colors adjacent` didn't find it).

Comment: Ehh, I think so yeah. The other one did come first. And otherwise, for the sake of good housekeeping, eventually one of the questions will be answered and the other marked as a duplicate. I'd recommend you edit/improve the other question too, especially add the links to Quora and Puzzling. And if you don't add a bounty on the other question, I (eventually) will. I want to [go talk to PuzzlingSE about something](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6441/45155) first.

Comment: I've put a bounty on the https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2794292/permutations-of-rubiks-cube-such-that-no-adjacent-sticker-is-the-same but not even a single comment or answer till yet.